# Add submenu in a Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to add submenu in one of item that It is in my menu like Wallapop that when click in a Item of Menu, open submenus:

[image]

This is my XML file, a simple LinerLayout with ToggleButtons to form the Menu:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout_container_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.runator.ui.widget.text.CustomToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/tooglebutton_menu_runsfeed"
        android:textOn="@string/menu_runsfeed"
        android:textOff="@string/menu_runsfeed"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/tg_menu_runsfeed"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/tg_menu_runsfeed"
        style="@style/textMenu.item"/>

    <com.ui.widget.text.CustomToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/tooglebutton_menu_leaderboards"
        android:textOn="@string/menu_leaderboards"
        android:textOff="@string/menu_leaderboards"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/tg_menu_leaderboards"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/tg_menu_leaderboards"
        style="@style/textMenu.item"/>

    <com.ui.widget.text.CustomToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/tooglebutton_menu_runators"
        android:textOn="@string/menu_runators"
        android:textOff="@string/menu_runators"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/tg_menu_runators"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/tg_menu_runators"
        style="@style/textMenu.item"/>

    <com.ui.widget.text.CustomToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/tooglebutton_menu_virtual_races"
        android:textOn="@string/menu_virtual_races"
        android:textOff="@string/menu_virtual_races"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/tg_menu_virtual_races"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/tg_menu_virtual_races"
        style="@style/textMenu.item"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I do not get what makes Wallapop, if anyone has any ideas I would be very grateful.

Comment: You can use a custom expandable list view inside navigation drawer. Go through [this sample](http://semycolon.blogspot.in/2014/11/first-android-app-step-13-view-pager.html).

Comment: http://www.karthikk.co.vu/2015/03/android-navigation-drawer-with-submenu.html

Comment: Following link may help you: http://www.karthikk.co.vu/2015/03/android-navigation-drawer-with-submenu.html

Comment: Yeah thanks! It is just what I need!